# Не нужный или ненужный?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Знания,( не ) нужные в жизни... Слитно или раздельно? Считается ли здесь зависимое слово?

Answer (score 3):

Это прилагательное с НЕ, можно заменить синонимом - Знания,лишние в жизни.-слитно. 
Наличие пояснительных слов при прилагательном, как правило, не влияет на слитное написание, только положительный смысл.

Но если Вы придаёте значение отрицания, то можно написать и раздельно. Вот если бы здесь были отрицательные местоимения или наречия(никому, нигде), далеко не, вовсе не,отнюдь не, тогда было бы точно отрицание.

А пока я отрицания не вижу. Я бы написала слитно.

Comment: А можно написать: Не нужные в жизни знания только мешают (авторский вариант)?

Comment: А что здесь изменилось, чтобы появилось отрицание? Лишние в жизни знания только мешают. Если бы это был ПРИЧАСТНЫЙ оборот, место в предложении играло бы роль, но это прилагательное.

Comment: Мне просто хотелось узнать, считаете ли вы такое предложение всегда утвердительным (усилительные варианты мы исключаем). Можно ли сказать, что мы НИКОГДА не должны писать  НЕ раздельно, если НЕ относится к необособленному определительному обороту?

Comment: Нет конечно. Я же сказала,что раздельное написание возможно, если автор видит в нём отрицание. Всё зависит от автора. Но если Ирине нужно для выполнения упражнения, а не для  СВОЕГО написания, то нужно искать, есть ли здесь отрицание.

Comment: Извините, еще один вопрос. А если переделать предложение: "Ненужные знания только мешают". Меня интересует вот что: существуют ли, по вашему мнению, такие синтаксические конструкции, которые можно считать только утвердительными и где не нужно постоянно упражняться в поисках отрицания.

Comment: В таком виде явно утвердительное высказывание, но можно ли считать его абсолютно утвердительным - не уверена, может существовать контекст, допускающий отрицание. По-моему, в русском языке нет ничего абсолютного, всё зависит от смысла, который придаёт высказыванию автор.Поэтому во всех правилах и пишут:"в основном", "обычно", но всегда есть исключения.

Answer (score 1):

> Наличие пояснительных слов при прилагательном, как правило, не влияет на слитное написание, только положительный смысл.

Нечто близкое к интуиции подсказывает мне, что это- один из случаев раздельного написания. 
А еще это Нечто шепчет, что процитированного выше правила оно не слышало о.о

Comment: А какой смысл писать НЕ раздельно, если есть слово "ненужный" которое ничем не отличается от варианта "не нужный"? Что на дает раздельное написание с точки зрения семантики?

Comment: Наличие зависимого слова. Пущай дилетантская, но почти всегда верная позиция.

Comment: Наличие зависимого слова влияет на написание полного причастия, а не прилагательного.

Answer (score 1):

не понимаю причины вопроса в данном случае. совершенно ясно, что речь идет о прилагательном. Значит, следует применить к нему правило написания не с прилагательными. Лично я для себя его значительно упростила, придумав слово "вода", которое включает все частицы, с которыми прилагательное  с не пишется раздельно: **в** - вовсе не; **о**- отнюдь не; **да**- далеко не. К ним следует добавить  все отрицательные местоимения   ( ничуть не. никому и т.п) И , конечно, не следует забывать о явных прилагательных- антонимах ( не широкий- а узкий, но   Неширокий, а глубокий канал
 и т.п. )  В вашем случае допустимо только слитное написание.Значит, пишем 
Абсолютно ненужные мне знания;  ненужные моей дочери знания.
Но!  Вовсе не нужные знания.  Никому не нужные знания. 
успехов!